# turtlemimic.launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run line: $ roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch

the error is : cannot locate [turtlemimic.launch] in package [beginner_tutorials]
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64683/turtlemimic.launch/) by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you've accidentally entered space before the name of launch file, when you copied from tutorial. Just remove the space. Did the same mistake also ^__^

---

Originally posted by [Natti](https://answers.ros.org/users/5133/natti/) with karma: 130 on 2013-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2013-06-17**:
Thanks, it works